# How to handle numbers in german format using jquery in SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

My SharePoint application is now in German regional settings. Hence, numbers takes format as 1.000,00 (for 1 thousand) instead of 1,000.00.
Is there a way to handle numbers in german format in jquery.

```
e.g. Amount=1.000,00 / 25,00.
```

Jquery gives error as NaN when doing above calculation.

my approach:

1. convert above numbers to english numbers (1000.00 & 25.00)
2. do jquery calculation (1000.00 / 25.00)
3. convert result (40,00) back to german format.

My approach is tedious since i have to deal with many such calculation in my application. Please suggest some better approach.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Is an calculated column or an workflow an option?

Comment: Where are you getting your German format numbers from? From the DOM, somewhere on the page?

Comment: @Patrick, Its a Number type column in SP list form. I want to do division operation e.g. Result = (Amt / Currency)

Comment: @Submits, Amt is the user inputs and I dont know what user will input. User can input english format (1,000.25) or German format (1.000,25).

Comment: Yes but how are you obtaining the value or Amt? From the DOM via jQuery? From a context object? From a REST call?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest trick for solving this would be to define a function in your js file which will remove the commas or dots between the numbers, like a simple replace will do.  And then perform the calculation

Comment: Yes ThatThatGuy, I applied the same trick but I have to apply the same function everywhere where numbers are used by my application. Any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jquery-numberformatter** to convert or handle numbers from German.

[Jquery NumberFormatter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-numberformatter/)